# How can I print an arraylist that is in one class, by a grouping from another class?

Tags: java, arraylist, methods, aggregate

I'm trying to print an arraylist that is in one class, based on one of the parameters from another class. Is this possible?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class TVShow {

    private String title;
    private String summary;
    private String releaseDate;
    private ArrayList<Episode> episodeList;


    public TVShow(String title, String summary, String releaseDate) {
        this.title = title;
        this.summary = summary;
        this.releaseDate = releaseDate;
        this.episodeList = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void addEpisode(Episode episode) {
        episodeList.add(episode);
    }

    public printEpisodesInSeason(int seasonNr) { 
        // How can I make this method access the other class and 
        // print the episodeList by season number?
        for (Episode episode : episodeList) {
             return System.out.println(episode.);
        }
    }
}


public class Episode {

    private int episodeNr;
    private int seasonNr;
    private String eTitle;
    private int runTime;

    public Episode(int episodeNr, int seasonNr, String eTitle, int runTime) {
        this.episodeNr = episodeNr;
        this.seasonNr = seasonNr;
        this.eTitle = eTitle;
        this.runTime = runTime;
    }
}
```

Comment: 2 words: getter, setter. I let you do the search

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I think I misinterpreted the question. You want to only print the episodes from a specific season. This can be done by applying the filter function on the `episodeList` as follows:

```
for (Episode episode : episodeList.stream().filter(episode -> episode.getSeasonNr() == seasonNr).collect(Collectors.toList())) 
{ ... }
```

This is ofcourse assuming you apply the getter setter pattern as described below before I edited the answer.

The `filter` function takes an anonymous function and applies it to all members of a collection. This way, only the episodes which have a season number that is supplied by the user are returned. Then, the foreach loop iterates over the resulting collection.

You could either make the members of Episode public by defining:

```
public class Episode {

    public int episodeNr;
    public int seasonNr;
    public String eTitle;
    public int runTime;

    public Episode(int episodeNr, int seasonNr, String eTitle, int runTime) {
        this.episodeNr = episodeNr;
        this.seasonNr = seasonNr;
        this.eTitle = eTitle;
        this.runTime = runTime;
    }
}
```

But this is seen as bad practice. The better way to do it is by defining methods in your Episode class to return the value of the class' fields like for example:

```
public class Episode {

    public int episodeNr;
    public int seasonNr;
    public String eTitle;
    public int runTime;

    public Episode(int episodeNr, int seasonNr, String eTitle, int runTime) {
        this.episodeNr = episodeNr;
        this.seasonNr = seasonNr;
        this.eTitle = eTitle;
        this.runTime = runTime;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return this.eTitle;
    }
}
```

This practice is called getters and setters and it positively impacts the encapsulation of the code. You could then obtain the value of the Episode's members by calling, for example `episode.getTitle()`.

Comment: Yes I only wanted to print from a specific season.
When I try your method I get erroor messages. When I hover filter it says: Cannot resolve method 'filter (lambda expression)' and when I hover episode.getSeasonNr() it says it  cannot resolve method, even though I added the getter to the episode class.

    public printEpisodesInSeason(int seasonNr) {
        for (Episode episode : episodeList.filter(episode -> episode.getSeasonNr() == seasonNr)) {
             return System.out.println(episode.getSeasonNr(seasonNr));
        }

Comment: @silverknight52 the top of my answer should provide an iterable List containing only the episodes of the specified season number. I haven't tested the code but it should look a lot like that.  You could maybe even leave the `.stream() and .collect()` part out

Comment: I finally got it to work! Thank you so much for your help.!